# Android Studio spinner ItemSlectedListener

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

How can I show the districts in spinner 2 according to the science of spinner 1?
NOTE = Iller = english(Cities)
[code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsdNF.png)

[code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZHym.png)

[code3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTQqJ.png)
[json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnUJL.png)

Comment: Please post text as text and not as picture.It's easier to read, search and copy-paste that way - even if you don't want to have it read to you by a machine

Comment: have you tried to have an instance of the adapter of spinner 2 in spinner 1 and update spinner 2 data depend on spinner 1 selection?